# Insert unstructured records into database

Tags: oracle, unix, database-administration, flat-file, sql-loader

I have a flat file with about half a million records in this format:

```
last_login=2014022
BPN=1234567890
first_last_names=portal admin
username=portal_admin
email=portal_admin@gmail.com

last_login=2010092
username=UCES1005
BPN=1001117643
email=deepak.prakash@pse
first_last_names=1026 BROAD ASSOCIATES

last_login=2014040
email=rgomes1@optonline.net
username=rgomes1
first_last_names=Robert Gomes
BPN=1001928140
```

I need to populate a table with these records. The first word is the column name and the second is the value. Each record is separated by a new line.

What is the best way or how do I import this data into a database? (Oracle or Access DB)

Comment: In what way is this "unstructured"? Looks pretty structured to me. All three records in your example have exactly the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would use plsql and read the file line by line.

Use:

```
UTL_FILE.FOPEN()
UTL_FILE.GET_LINE()
etc...
```

Process each line as needed.